# Going Back To 1982

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about this usage of the phrase "*going back to*" in some [article](http://awealthofcommonsense.com/2015/12/sp-500-streaks/):

> It’s pretty crazy when you consider that there was just one down year in the stock market from 1982-1999, an eighteen year window. In fact, ***going back to 1982***, there have been just five down years in the S&P 500.

As used in the article, "*going back to*" seems to mean "*since*".  But I cannot find a dictionary definition that fit this usage.  So, could the usage be Wall Street technical jargon?

Answer (score 3):

No dictionary will list all definitions of all words.  *Go,* in particular is used in so many ways there are bound to be some meanings left out.  In this case, though, the fourth definition in my Webster's Riverside seems to fit:  *`4a` to extend between two points.*  The example fragment in my dictionary is *curtains **going** from floor to ceiling.*

In your example sentence, we are considering *[a time period] **going** [from the present]  back to 1982.*

Comment: So, the original was poorly written?  And it should be written as:  " In fact, ***in the period*** going ***from the present*** back to 1982, there have been just five down years in the S&P 500."  ?

Comment: No the original was written just fine.  All of these options would sound fine: `1` _In fact, going from the present back to 1982..._ `2` _In fact, in the period going from the present back to 1982..._ `3` _In fact, going from the present back to 1982_ `4` _In fact, in the period going back to 1982..._  The writer gets to choose.   Most of the time, I would choose the way this author did - keeping it short and simple.  As always, English allows [and requires] that the reader makes assumptions from context.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about what it means in this context. It isn't really jargon. The phrase is an idiom that can be used in many contexts.

Comment: But the usage is not in dictionaries.

Comment: @meatie Yes, [it is](http://onelook.com/?w=going+back&ls=a) (sense 2 in Collins, sense 16a in TFD, and others); you appear once again to be using the word "dictionaries" to mean "things I've heard before or I intuitively approve of". You might get in the habit of checking actual dictionaries.